# Firebase Crashlytics not displaying Logs on Android in Lock Task Mode

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics, kiosk

I am currently facing an issue with Firebase Crashlytics on my Android application. While the crashes are being reported in the Firebase console, the logs associated with these crashes are not being displayed. This issue only occurs when the application is in Lock Task Mode.

[image: Firbase Console no logs on crash]

And sometime there are no logs like this:
[image]

I mentioned that this issue only occurs when the application is in Lock Task Mode. Because when I am not in lock task mode the logs are displayed fine.

So my guess was that probably some package was being blocked in the lock task mode. Altough I don't see any exception/error in logs on Android Studio when the crash occurs.

- I have tried allowing all the associated packages incase some package is being blocked by lock task mode that might be preventing to send logs. But no success. I tried allowing all these packages:

1. "com.google.gms.google-services"
2. "com.google.firebase"
3. "com.google.android.gms"
4. "cat.ereza"
5. "com.google.firebase.crashlytics"
6. "au.com.thermalog/com.google.android"
7. "au.com.thermalog/com.google.firebase"

- I changed the device policies which are set in ...res/xml/device_admin.xml, but no success. Since my app is an Admin App.
- I also tried to turn on the automatic crashlytics data collection. By setting the meta-data for `firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled` to `true`. As suggested in the docs for firebase crashlytics.

Any help, insights, or guidance regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.